# passing data between pages through navigator in ajax request success function

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, phonegap-desktop-app

in my angular js controller i have an ajax request which is returning me an object :

```js
var d= $myformdata;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data:  d,
success: function(message){
console.log(message);
myNavigator.pushPage('confirmation.html', {msg: message} );
$scope.msg =  myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.msg;
console.log($scope.msg);
}
 });
else{ alert($err_msg); }
```

i get the response(message) but when i try to push the data to access it on confirmation page it says undefined.
it would be pleasure if anyone could help

Comment: What is `myNavigator`..?

Comment: mynavigator is the page navigator(onsen ui) and confirmation.html is the page i want to get the response(message) @TJ

Comment: We have no idea how your controllers or services work or what confirmation page does or what specifically is undefined. Show all relevant code

Comment: confirmation page just shows the response object iam getting from ajax request @charlietfl

Comment: Object {ProviderReservation: "#####", AirReservation: "#####", UniversalLocator: "#####", all_segments: Array[5], pricing: Object…}
this is the response iam getting from ajax req. i just want to navigate to the page with the above object to set the view. i hope u get it now

Comment: giving negative marks wont stop me from learning finally i solved it myself ;p

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you accessing the data in the confirmation page, please check the below example.

Controller

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: serviceURL+'xxxxxxxx',
        data: {d},
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (response) {          
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.profiledata = JSON.parse(response).data;
            $scope.$apply();
        },      
        error: function (response) {
            $scope.error = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myProfile">
            <div class="profile-card">
                <img src={{profiledata.profile_image_url}} class="profile-image">
                <div class="profile-name">{{profiledata.firstname}} {{profiledata.lastname}}</div>
                <div class="profile-id">{{profiledata.email}}</div>
                <div class="profile-id">{{profiledata.phone}}</div>
            </div>  
        </div>
```